# Is it possible to create multiple transactions programmaticaly inside a ledger in a contract test in Corda?

Tags: kotlin, corda

Is it possible to create multiple transactions programmaticaly inside a ledger in a contract test in Corda? When I remove the forEach loop and copy and paste the code for each transaction (changing the output state to match what I wanna test) everything works as expected. But if I try to refactor it and generate transactions programmaticaly inside forEach loop as in the code example, my test fails.

```
@Test
fun simpleTest() {
    ledger {
        listOf(...).forEach { 
            transaction {
                command(participants, Commands.Command())
                input(Contract.ID, inputState)
                output(Contract.ID, outputState)
                failsWith("message")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add more context to your question? What's the purpose of creating multiple transactions?

Comment: I wanna create a test which fails for all invalid input states for a given command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your reply to my comment; I think you should try using `tweak`.
In the example below you'll see how my transaction has the same command and output but I can tweak it and try different inputs:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Testing different inputs.")
public void testDifferentInputs() {
    CustomState goodInput = new CustomState();
    CustomState badInput1 = new CustomState();
    CustomState badInput2 = new CustomState();
    CustomState output = new CustomState();

    ledger(ledgerServices, l -> {
        l.transaction(tx -> {
            // Same output and command.
            tx.output("mypackage.CustomState", output);
            tx.command(Collections.singletonList(myNode.getPublicKey()), new CustomStateContract.Commands.Create());
            // Tweak allows to tweak the transaction, in this case we're using bad input #1 and the transaction should fail.
            tx.tweak(tw -> {
                tw.input("mypackage.CustomState", badInput1);               
                return tw.failsWith("Bad Input State.");
            });
            // Tweak allows to tweak the transaction, in this case we're using bad input #2 and the transaction should fail.
            tx.tweak(tw -> {
                tw.input("mypackage.CustomState", badInput2);               
                return tw.failsWith("Bad Input State.");
            });
            // After the tweak we are using the good input and the transaction should pass.
            tx.input("mypackage.CustomState", goodInput);           
            return tx.verifies();
        });
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    });
}
```

More examples here: https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-test-dsl.html

Comment: Please pay attention that inside the `tweak` block the transaction is `tw` not `tx`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is better than repeating each transaction, but it is not possible to create those tweaks programmatically? I still need to repeat all the code for each bad input.

Comment: I never tried to create a loop, I think `tweak` is the right way because you will be getting different error messages depending on what's bad in your input, so the error message inside `tw.failsWith(error_message)` should match the error that your state contract raised. I still don't understand the purpose of the loop, if it's creating the same input/output/command then the error message will be the same.

Comment: Error message will be the same. Each input will contain an invalid enum value which will cause the same error.

Comment: I see. Well I gave you an option; maybe you'll find something better.

Comment: Another reason I wanted to do that in a loop is that I need to generate a bad input for each enum value. With the loop I wouldn't have to update the test if a create a new enum value.